# How to query and update Django model JsonField?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

Im working on a project where using Django JSONField to store json data for the instance. When i try to query the object as per official documentation, its not working as expected. Im uanble to query the object to update the key value inside the jsonfield. Please find the below details for your reference and help to to achelve the desired result.

**Model**

```
class PosOrder(models.Model):
store = models.ForeignKey('store.Store', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
order_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
customer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
order_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
order_discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
order_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
coupon = models.ForeignKey('shoppingcoupon.ShoppingCoupon', on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
null=True, blank=True)
order_grand_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, choices=(
    ('cash', 'Cash'), ('card', 'Card'), ('online', 'Online')))
order_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, choices=order_status)
payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, 
choices=payment_status)
payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
order_data = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
created_by = models.ForeignKey('hrms.Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
blank=True)
```

**Jsonfield is like**

```
{"id": 408, "store": {"id": 1, "name": "Salt Lake"}, "order_number": "POS408", 
"customer_phone": "9877454577", "order_status": "processed", "payment_status": null
, "payment_method": "cash", "created_at": "2022-08-09T11:38:37.207775+05:30", "created_by": 
{"id": 5, "code": "RMS003"}, "get_order_total": 39206, "get_order_tota
l_discount_amount": 2232, "get_order_total_without_tax": 32730, "get_order_total_tax": 6476, 
"ordered_items": [{"id": 41, "item": {"id": 3, "product": {"id": 3, "
sku": "TM002", "name": "Striped Men Polo Neck White, Blue, Yellow T-Shirt", "barcode": 
"552123", "manufacturer": null, "created_at": "2022-08-06T15:04:05.509651+0
5:30", "category": 1, "brand": null, "size": null, "color": null, "vendor": null, 
"created_by": 9}, "mrp": "1599.00", "price_without_tax": "1427.68", "tax": 12, "
tax_amount": "154.19", "discount_percentage": "10.00", "discount_amount": "142.77", "price": 
"1439.10", "stock": 100, "created_at": "2022-08-07T17:13:33.640401+05
:30", "updated_at": "2022-08-07T17:13:33.639749+05:30", "store": 1, "created_by": 9, "offers": 
[]}, "quantity": 2, "mrp": "1599.00", "price": "1439.10", "discount
": "319.80", "tax": "22.84", "mrp_total": "3198.00", "total_without_tax": "2855.36", "total": 
"2878.20", "is_returned": false, "is_exchanged": false, "order": 408
, "offer": null}, {"id": 42, "item": {"id": 2, "product": {"id": 2, "sku": "TFM01", "name": 
"Demo 1", "barcode": "012345", "manufacturer": null, "created_at": "20
22-07-29T14:32:14.900200+05:30", "category": 1, "brand": 1, "size": 1, "color": 1, "vendor": 
null, "created_by": null}, "mrp": "38240.00", "price_without_tax": "2
9875.00", "tax": 28, "tax_amount": "7946.75", "discount_percentage": "5.00", 
"discount_amount": "1493.75", "price": "36328.00", "stock": 100, "created_at": "2022-
08-06T12:15:45.279121+05:30", "updated_at": "2022-08-06T12:15:38+05:30", "store": 1, 
"created_by": 1, "offers": [1, 2]}, "quantity": 1, "mrp": "38240.00", "price"
: "36328.00", "discount": "1912.00", "tax": "6453.00", "mrp_total": "38240.00", 
"total_without_tax": "29875.00", "total": "36328.00", "is_returned": false, "is_ex
changed": false, "order": 408, "offer": null}]}
```

**I want to upadete value with is_returned key**

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide code of how you're querying data

Comment: I have tried several methods as per documentation and codes available online. This was last one.   PosOrder.objects.get(order_data__order_number__ordered_items__id=item_id)

Comment: You've provided invalid format of json data please provide valid format so we can reproduce problem

Comment: This is the data being saved to databsae. Im using json.dumps while saving data. Below is the code is use to save data. order.order_data = json.dumps(OrderDataSerializer(order).data)

Comment: I have resolved this issue. by removing json.dumps while saving the data.